# OpenRefine cell.cross creates column but fills zero rows

Tags: openrefine, grel

I have two projects with a column in common I am attempting to merge.

Project 1 has columns Date Published, Type, Story, Subtopics and Author
Project 2 has columns PageTitle, UniquePageviews and AvgTimeOnPage

PageTitle and Story have equivalent values. I want to add UniquePageviews and AvgTimeOnPage to Project 1.

When I use GREL forEach(cross(cell,"Project2","PageTitle"),v,v.cells["AvgTimeOnPage"].value)[0] (either manually or using VIB-Bits extension), I am notified that two new columns have been created ... but "by filling 0 rows." The new columns are blank except for the header, which is added correctly.

How do I get cell.cross to fill any of the rows it says it's filling?

Edit: Database samples here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQIWs.jpg

Project 1:

```
Date published    Type          Story                                                                  Subtopic(s)                       Author
4/30/2018        News in Brief Last year's solar eclipse set off a wave in the upper atmosphere       Planetary Science, Earth           Lisa Grossman
4/30/2018        News in Brief New genetic details may help roses come up smelling like, well, roses     Plants, Genetics                Susan Milius
4/30/2018       Science Visualized  See (and hear) the stunning diversity of bowhead whales' songs     Animals, Biophysics, Ecology      Helen Thompson
4/29/2018        News   New genetic sleuthing tools helped track down the Golden State Killer suspect   Genetics, Science & Society      Tina Hesman Saey
```

Project 2:

```
PageTitle                                                          UniquePageviews                AvgTimeOnPage
The truth about animals isn't always pretty                            63398                  Sun Dec 31 00:03:06 EST 1899
Birds get their internal compass from this newly ID'd eye protein      53566    Sun Dec 31 00:03:30 EST 1899
Last year's solar eclipse set off a heat wave in the upper atmosphere   35496    Sun Dec 31 00:07:03 EST 1899
City heat is getting hazardous for humans                              32199   Sun Dec 31 00:05:49 EST 1899
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your two datasets please ?

Comment: Added to description, here for convenience https://imgur.com/a/fRGhhNw

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to import a imgur screenshot on OpenRefine in order to make tests.

Comment: Added to descriptions. Sorry for formatting, not sure how to make good tables here. And yes the Time on Page column is an abomination. That's a separate issue.

Comment: In your example, there is absolutely no relation between the "story" column and the "PageTitle" column. All the values are completely different. Difficult to say what's the problem. You should try to create a join column in both dataset by using `value.fingerprint()`, which will remove extraspaces and other stuffs that prevent an exact match.

Comment: In the interest of time, I didn't include all 100+ rows -- the values absolutely match (one of the matches, "Last year's solar eclipse..." is in the example). But I'll try a join column anyway.

Comment: Clustering found exactly two duplicates to merge. I don't think it's a formatting issue. Any other ideas? I literally started using this program yesterday and I'm completely at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work. Lessons learned:

- Use 2.8, not 3.0 beta
- Transform smart quotes to regular quotes

  value.replace(/[\u2018\u2019\u201A\u201B\u2032\u2035]/,"'")

Comment: When I'm doing this kind of cross in OR I often create a special 'key column' in both projects using `value.fingerprint()` to create a standard key. This avoids issues like the presence of smart quotes etc. - although creates some chances of duplicate keys